# Adding a non-button hyperlink to MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink, mfc

I am trying to add a hyperlink that will direct a user of the application to a website.  I see that MFC has a built in "MFC Link Control".  In the dialog-editor. My hyperlinks look to work correctly.
[image]

When I debug my program, the links instead turn into buttons.
[image]

Is there a way to add non-button hyperlinks?
Thanks.

Comment: _When I debug my program, the links instead turn into buttons_ - What does this mean?  I've got a dialog with a link and it does not look like a button.  Do you have a conflict with another control somewhere in the code?  I should also add, I'm using VS 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CButton` is the natural base class of `CMFCLinkCtrl`. If it misses certain key properies, `CMFCLinkCtrl` will revert back to a `CButton`. My bet is on the URL. Try this:

```
CMFCLinkCtrl m_btnLink; // <-- associate with your control!
...
BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{
    ...
    m_btnLink.SetURL(_T("http://www.example.com"));
    m_btnLink.SetTooltip(_T("Link to my site"));
    m_btnLink.SizeToContent();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Drag `SysLink` from `Toolbox` to your dialog box. Double click it and add this line to `void` function:

```
ShellExecute(
    NULL, // or your can use GetSafeHwnd()
    L"open", 
    L"http://stackoverflow.com/a/29181060/4057688", 
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    SW_SHOWNORMAL
    );
```

For more information [visit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hope to be useful.

Comment: Not good to hardcode a x86 Google Chrome path.. as my 64bit computer uses Google Chrome 64bit which is installed in `C:\Program Files\Google` instead

Comment: `ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://stackoverflow.com/a/29181060/4057688",NULL, NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);` I think this is best solution it opens whatever browser you have set as default browser for your computer.